# Can I use Redux with MongoDB in one project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, mongodb, redux

I am started learn NodeJS + MongoDB. Before that, I studied React + Redux. As I understand MongoDB replaces Redux or is it not? If not, what data should be stored in Redux and what data in MongoDB?

---

Comment: React and redux are frontend technologies and mongodb and nodejs are backend technologies. So no mongodb does not replace redux they are not even close to the same thing.

Comment: Imagine you have some data that you use in different paths of you app. You could fetch it once initializing application, store it in Redux and than reuse stored data.
Basic example is user information. You don't want to fetch it on every page. And moreover this will help you speed up your up, because you could fetch some data once and reuse it everywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redux is state management which is used to transfer data between components, But this data is lost when the tab of browser closes or refreshes.

[redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org) can be used to store data in the user's browser, which stores the redux data in the browser's local storage.

But MongoDB is a server-side database for storing data on the server side permanently. To get information in Front-End, a request must be sent to the server using the API and the Back-End data must be sent to the front-end or the user. In general, information including user information and user login information, etc. should be stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Redux is an state manager normally used in React Applications to share the application state globally across component tree.
The MongoDB is a NoSQL database manager used to store your application data.
i think they are not equivalent.